# Cast/Convert tree structure to different type

Tags: c#, data-structures, casting, tree

If I have the class:

```
class NodeA
{
      public string Name{get;set;}
      public List<NodeA> Children {get;set;}
      // etc some other properties
}
```

and some other class:

```
class NodeB
{
      public string Name;
      public IEnumerable<NodeB> Children;
      // etc some other fields;
}
```

If I need to convert a NodeB object to of type NodeA what will be the best approach? Create a wrapper class? If I have to create a wrapper class how could I create it so that all the wpf controls will still be able to successfully bind to the properties?

- Reason why I need to create such cast:

  There was an old algorithm that was used on a program that return the list of symbols (IMemorySymbol) in a compiled program. We have worked and created a new algorithm and the fields and properties are somewhat different (ISymbolElem). We need to perform a temporary cast in order to display the properties in the view of the wpf application.

Comment: Well, you can't "cast" it because their is no implicit conversion.  You could conceivably "convert" it...somehow.

Comment: yeah so I will have to basically have to traverse the whole tree and somehow convert it that way?

Comment: That basically what Automapper does out of the box. It uses reflection to traverse through all the properties, and copy the data. What it does - it provides You a nice and comfy way of describing how to map the props. So it's more readable for 5 pages of ForEach loops

Comment: Well, my above comment was mostly a terminology issue.  "casting" is treating one object as if it is a different class; that won't work here.  "Converting" is making a new object that is of a different class, but that is logically representing the same value or thing.  Looking at what you have, my guess is also that you can't just convert one node; you'll need to convert the entire tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple approaches...

**Copy Constructor**

have a NodeA and NodeB contain a constructor which takes the opposite:

```
class NodeA 
{ 
    public string Name{get;set;} 
    public List<NodeA> Children {get;set;} 

    // COPY CTOR
    public NodeA(NodeB copy)
    {
        this.Name = copy.Name;
        this.Children = new List<NodeA>(copy.Children.Select(b => new NodeA(b));
        //copy other props
    }
}
```

**Explicit or Implicit Operator**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx

explicit you would cast like `NodeA a = (NodeA)b;`, while implicit you can skip the parens.

```
public static explicit operator NodeA(NodeB b)
{
    //if copy ctor is defined you can call one from the other, else
    NodeA a = new NodeA();
    a.Name = b.Name;
    a.Children = new List<NodeA>();

    foreach (NodeB child in b.Children)
    {
        a.Children.Add((NodeA)child);
    }
}
```

Comment: A note about implicit/explict cast operators.  You should really only use such conversions if the two types are related, or if such a conversion makes sense (compare against converting between Tomatoes and TimeSpan).  The OP's types look related, so this would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about coupling the implementation of `NodeA` to `NodeB`, then add a copy constructor as follows:

```
class NodeA
{
    public NodeA() { }
    public NodeA(NodeB node)
    {
        Name = node.Name;
        Children = node.Children.Select(n => new NodeA(n)).ToList();
    }

    public string Name{get;set;}
    public List<NodeA> Children {get;set;}
    // etc some other properties
}
```

If coupling is a concern, then you can create a [`Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx)-style class that does the conversion for you.  Note that the [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) framework generates these types of conversions for you by use of reflection over the source and target types.

Answer (score 1):

How about inheriting from a common interface?

```
interface INode {
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<INode> Children {get;set;}
}

class NodeA : INode {
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public List<NodeA> Children {get;set;}
  // etc some other properties
}

class NodeB : INode {
  public string Name;
  public IEnumerable<NodeB> Children;
  // etc some other fields;
}

void myMethod() {
  INode nodeB = new NodeB();
  INode nodeA = nodeB;
}
```